# Silex gives empty response if HTTP Status code != 200

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, cors, silex

I'm trying to set up a small Silex RESTFul server, and now I'm playing around with HTTP Headers.

One **GET** function checks **If-Modified-Since** header, and compares with database's **Last-Modified** item.

Here's a small code sample:

```
if($hasModifications){
  $response = [items]
  $statusCode = 200;
} else {
  $response = ['result'=>'no modifications'];
  $statusCode = 304;
}
return $app->json($response,$statusCode,$headers);
```

Whenever **$statuscode!=200**, I only get a blank page and also no custom header gets sent. This also breaks CORS because I can't set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header.

Should I be doing it some other way?

(PS: this is not the actual code, and also if I replace **$statusCode** for 200, then everything works back as normal)

**Update:**
So far, I guess from what I've been reading, that 304 statuses shouldn't send anything on response's body. But what about headers? If I don't comply with CORS, then the AngularJS Frontend will fail and I wouldn't be able to catch the "Not Modified" exception!.
Obviously, I can figure it out some other way. But it would be nice if I could have both things working properly (REST+CORS)!

**Update 2:**

```
var_dump($headers)
array(4) {
  ["Last-Modified"]=> string(29) "Fri, 21 Aug 2015 22:47:53 GMT"
  ["X-Status-Code"]=> int(304) 
  ["Cache-Control"]=> string(25) "post-check=0, pre-check=0" 
  ["Pragma"]=> string(8) "no-cache"
}
```

Notice that I'm using **X-Status-Code** to inform the true HTTP Status.
Right now, the response line of code goes as follows:

```
return $app->json($response,200,$headers);
```

If I changed **200** to **304**, I can't see the output of var_dump (gives me an empty page). Also if I set 304 status with no header parameter, it is still the same.
Seems like **return** or **$app->json** clears the HeaderBag, since I'm using **JDesrosiers\Silex\Provider\CorsServiceProvider()**, and those headers parameters also get cleared.

This is the Raw HTTP Response taken from Firefox with Status Code **304**:

```
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 19:52:18 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

And this, with Status Code **200**:

```
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 22 Aug 2015 19:53:12 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 22:47:53 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
X-Status-Code: 304
```

Comment: can you post the output of ```var_dump($headers)```?

Comment: Added var_dump($headers), some other tests and HTTP raw responses in both cases (200 and 304) in edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache strips out CORS headers on 304 status codes.

You can read more in issue [#51223](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51223) and you can also find a patch which will fix this problem.

If you don't want or you can't recompile Apache, you could try running Nginx, which will leave the CORS headers in place.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty unfortunate.. I can switch here on my local setup but this will run on a shared host so there's no chance I can do that. Even if I set those parameters via .htaccess, they're gonna get stripped out? So far, then, the solution for this is setting status to 200 and sending X-Status-Code header with the correct value. Thanks, Alexandru.

Comment: According to [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5), `If the conditional GET used a strong cache validator the response SHOULD NOT include other entity-headers.`. And because CORS headers are unrecognised, they are treated as entity-headers. (see [Section 6 from RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)). So from my perspective, Apache follows the spec. However, you have more info about how to setup Apache for CORS, on [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) website.